# iOS: Is AFCache Still Current? Can it do this (see below). Any other suggestions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, uiwebview

I'm looking for a solution to cache a UIWebView, including all code, images and links etc while on wifi, and then while on anything other than wifi the page is loaded from the cache. Once the user is connected to wifi again I want it to run another full cache and delete the old one.

Can anybody help with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it answers your question or help your cause but when you loading request in `UIWebView` there is possibility to load the data from cache if it has been loaded earlier using `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad`

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:10.0f];
    return request;

[myWebView loadRequest:request];
```

you could explore other properties for [cacchePolicy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLRequest/cachePolicy) according to your need

Comment: I had a look at this, does it empty the cache ever? Is it overwritten by a new download of a page?

Comment: if you check the other properties i have provided a link in answer you might get your answer

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for something similar.
What I found usefull was http://robnapier.net/blog/offline-uiwebview-nsurlprotocol-588

Comment: The trouble with this is I need to be able to follow links as well - this is only for the first visible page I believe?